# sql query to count multiple defined columns within one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I have been looking through this website to try and a) understand my problem better and b) to to find some help to solve it but it seems everything i've seen is slightly different to my problem so im here to ask for some advice please :)

i have the following query

```
SELECT *, 
(date_end < 1392569012) AS expired, 
(date_start > 1392569012) AS pending, 
(date_end > 1392569012 && date_start <= 1392569012) AS active 
FROM tbl_events AS event 
LEFT JOIN tbl_event_events AS ee ON event.event_id = ee.event_id
WHERE event.event_type = 5 && event.user_id = '".$user->getUserID()."'
ORDER BY expired,pending,active
```

which determins the status of a listing.

now what i want to do is count the number of active, pending and expired listings

this is my updated query, but it only returns 1 row but the correct sum values?

```
SELECT *, 
SUM(date_end < 1392569012) AS expiredCount,
SUM(date_start > 1392569012) AS pendingCount, 
SUM(date_end > 1392569012 && date_start <= 1392569012) AS activeCount,              
(date_end < 1392569012) AS expired, 
(date_start > 1392569012) AS pending, 
(date_end > 1392569012 && date_start <= 1392569012) AS active 
FROM tbl_events AS event 
LEFT JOIN tbl_job_events AS jobvent ON event.event_id = jobvent.event_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_job_department AS jdept ON event.event_id = jdept.event_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_departments as dept ON jdept.department_id = dept.department_id 
WHERE event.event_type = 2 && event.user_id = '".$user->getUserID()."'
ORDER BY expired,pending,active
```

could someone help me get this working please!

thanks for any help

Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since active will be 1 for that filter and 0 for others, add sum to the active filter to get the count of rows which satisfies that filter.

```
SELECT *, ( SELECT  SUM(date_end > 1392569012 && date_start <= 1392569012)
FROM tbl_events AS event 
LEFT JOIN tbl_event_events AS ee ON event.event_id = ee.event_id
WHERE event.event_type = 5 && event.user_id = '".$user->getUserID()."'
ORDER BY expired,pending,active),
(date_end < 1392569012) AS expired, 
(date_start > 1392569012) AS pending, 
(date_end > 1392569012 && date_start <= 1392569012) AS active 
FROM tbl_events AS event 
LEFT JOIN tbl_event_events AS ee ON event.event_id = ee.event_id
WHERE event.event_type = 5 && event.user_id = '".$user->getUserID()."'
ORDER BY expired,pending,active
```

Comment: on further inspection this is only returning a max of 1 row for each type of listing? any ideas? thanks

Comment: you mean this query returns 1 row? or the SUM field returns value 1?

Comment: the query returns 1 row.

Comment: added sum query as a subquery try now

Comment: it didnt like the first set order by's so i removed them and now its not returning any rows? thanks

Comment: it has nothing to do with my addition. i didn't change where condition. print out the query and check for syntax errors.

Comment: ok got the query working, not sure why it wasnt returning any rows but its still returning a sum value of 1 :( thanks

Comment: run the subquery alone, is it still giving you the value 1?

Comment: ok got it working :) didnt relise the multiple where statements. to include multiple sums would i need to add multiple sub queries? many thanks

Comment: brilliant got multi sub queries working too, thank you very much for your help and patience!!!